# Golden Ratio within quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Could you help with a Euclidean plane geometry problem?
If WXYZ is a rectangle, U is on XY and V is on YZ. We know that the following triangles are of equal area: triangle WXU, triangle UYV, triangle VZW. If a=XU, b=UY, c=YV, d=VZ, then prove that b/a will be the same as c/d and that b/a is the golden ratio.

Comment: (1) Do you mean that the areas of the triangles are equal, or that the triangles are congruent? (2) If $V$ is on $YZ$, there is no triangle $VYZ$.

Comment: You don't happen to have a nice diagram on you, do you?

Comment: J.M.  I would like to upload a diagram, but I'm not sure how to draw it on this site.  I would not mind drawing free hand.

Comment: You can upload any pic (made with e.g. mspaint on windows) to imgur and provide the url here; someone with sufficient rep (I forgot what the threshold is) will swoop in and put it into your post.

Comment: You should be able to upload a picture here. Sixth button from the left of the panel above the text box, there is an image uploader. Follow the instructions.

Comment: @J.M., isn't there a threshhold for that?

Comment: @Gerry, he's got 16 rep, which is sufficient if memory serves...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of triangle $WXU$ is $\frac12a(c+d)$; that of triangle $UYV$ is $\frac12bc$; and that of triangle $VZW$ is $\frac12d(a+b)$. If these areas are equal, we have $$\frac12a(c+d)=\frac12bc=\frac12d(a+b)$$ and hence $ac+ad=bc=ad+bd$.

The first part of the answer now follows very easily from the fact that $ac+ad=ad+bd$; just do a little algebra.

Once you’ve shown the first part, divide the equation $ac+ad=bc$ by $bd$ to get $$\frac{a}b\left(\frac{c}d+1\right)=\frac{c}d\;,$$ let $x=\dfrac{b}a$, and solve for $x$ to complete the problem.

Here’s a diagram, not to scale:

[image]

Comment: The areas of the triangles are all congruent.  I can see how that reads ambiguously.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user31284: It makes no sense to say that the areas are congruent: congruence is a property of *shapes*, and areas are *numbers*. It seems that what you meant is simply that the areas are equal.

Comment: My mistake.  I will edit this.

Comment: @user31284: That’s the percentage of your questions for which you have accepted an answer. See [this part of the FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) to learn how to accept an answer.